# SharePoint Calendar sync between different sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

Is there any possibility about syncing calendars between 2 different sites.

a.examplesite.com sharepoint 2013
b.anothersite.com Online SharePoint

Let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync Calendar list between SharePoint online and SharePoint server, I suggest you create a custom tile for the list and configure hybrid app launcher to intergrate with SharePoint server.

I dont't think we could sync calendar list between different tenant.

Here are some articles for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/customize-the-app-launcher?view=o365-worldwide

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/hybrid/sharepoint-hybrid-sites-and-search?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/hybrid/the-extensible-hybrid-app-launcher